# how to save a bitmap object in application state in wp7?

Tags: xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-7

How to save bitmap object in application state in windows phone 7??

Thanks,
balaram.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of options, depending on your need & scenario:

a) create a WriteableBitmap and then save its Pixels property (an array of int)
b) if you have the original stream this bitmap was created from, you can save this stream as byte array
c) if the bitmap was created from URI, you can save the URI and re-create it from that URI later (if this is OK for your scenario)

Thanks,
Stefan Wick - Microsoft Silverlight